# Stop Animation to starting again on scrolling back

Tags: android

I want to highlight the row items which are new and for that I am dispalying an image along all the new row items. (Note: All the row items are loaded together and only the unread ones are highlighted). 
I have a ImageView as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/unreaddead"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

(I am setting the color in the adapter itself by using "setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

I have been trying to Fade the Image in highlighted row-items in a ListView. For that I am using animation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="3000" android:repeatCount="0"/></set>
```

And I am attaching the animation with rowitems in the adapter as:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ObjectPerCourseDeadline currentObject = obj.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.supercontext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_deadline_layout,
            parent, false);

    final View unreadnot = rowView.findViewById(R.id.unreaddead);
    unreadimg = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.unreaddead);
    fadeinanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_image);
    unreadimg.startAnimation(fadeinanimation);
    fadeinanimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            unreadnot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            unreadnot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    if(position < FragmentViewPager.deadnotlen){
        unreadnot.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        Log.d("color changes to blue","of background of listview");
    }

    Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.supercontext.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.supercontext.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(removeHTML(currentObject.getTitle()));
    title.setTypeface(tf2);
    if(currentObject.getBody().length()!=0)
    {
        TextView body = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.body);
        body.setTypeface(tf);
        body.setText(removeHTML(currentObject.getBody()));}
        TextView end = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.endDateTime);
        end.setTypeface(tf);
        end.setText(removeHTML(currentObject.getEndtime().split("\\+")[0]));
        TextView duration = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        duration.setTypeface(tf);
        duration.setText(removeHTML(currentObject.getTimestamp().split(" ")[0]));
    return rowView;
}
```

But this reloads even on scrolling which I don't want.  I just want to run this animation once and specially not on the scrolling

I know that is because the row items are loaded again but any better idea to do this?

**Edit 1**:

I have updated the getView function's code that I am using. Sorry for not providing enough details. Now The problem is that getView is called even on scrolling back on a certain row-item and thus the animation is happening again which I don't want.

Comment: Unclear where you have used your code. Paste in your complete java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I fixed this issue by maintaining a *static* variable which maintains the maximum position which has been displayed on the screen yet and thus I can apply animation only when the list is scrolled down first time. Below is the extract:

```
static Integer max_position = -1;

public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ObjectPerCourseDeadline currentObject = obj.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.supercontext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_deadline_layout,
            parent, false);

    final View unreadnot = rowView.findViewById(R.id.unreaddead);
    if( position > max_position ) {
        unreadimg = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.unreaddead);
        fadeinanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_image);
        unreadimg.startAnimation(fadeinanimation);
        fadeinanimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                unreadnot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                unreadnot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        max_position = position;
        unreadnot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    if(position < FragmentViewPager.deadnotlen && position >= max_position){
        unreadnot.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        Log.d("color changes to blue","of background of listview");
    }

    Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.supercontext.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.supercontext.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(removeHTML(currentObject.getTitle()));
    title.setTypeface(tf2);
    if(currentObject.getBody().length()!=0)
    {
        TextView body = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.body);
        body.setTypeface(tf);
        body.setText(removeHTML(currentObject.getBody()));}
        TextView end = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.endDateTime);
        end.setTypeface(tf);
        end.setText(removeHTML( currentObject.getEndtime().split("\\+")[0]));
        TextView duration = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        duration.setTypeface(tf);
        duration.setText(removeHTML(currentObject.getTimestamp().split(" ")[0]));

    return rowView;
    }
```

Any better solution is Welcome!.